# Code completion issues with the Scala-IDE and Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, scala, code-completion, scala-ide, eclipse-juno

I'm using Eclipse Juno with the Java (Java build 1.7.0_05-b05 64bit) and Scala-IDE plugin 
(Scala IDE for Eclipse  2.1.0.nightly-2_09-201207100348-f1d9c23 org.scala-ide.sdt.feature.feature.group scala-ide.org).

Below are my custom settings for Eclipse eclipse.ini:

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xss8m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1536m
-XX:PermSize=64m
-server
-Xverify:none
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Every-time I try to use code completion Eclipse throwing me 2 error windows:

```
The 'Code Recommenders Calls Proposals' proposal computer from
the 'org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp.calls' plug-in did
not complete normally.
The extension has thrown a runtime exception.
```

and

```
The 'Code Recommenders Overrides Proposals' proposal computer from
the 'org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp.overrides' plug-in did
not complete normally.
The extension has thrown a runtime exception.
```

My scala-ide log below shows:

```
[Xlint:cantFindType]
2012-07-10 15:37:29,404 ERROR [main] - System.err - 
[org.eclipse.jdt.launching] error can't determine modifiers of missing type
org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.wizards.imports.PluginImportHelper
when weaving type org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
[Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**:
After disabling code Recommenders I'm getting a different error in my Slaca-Ide log:

```
2012-07-10 16:10:24,342 ERROR [main] - System.err - [org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui] 
error can't determine modifiers of missing type
org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.wizards.imports.PluginImportHelper
when weaving type org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointAdapter
when weaving classes
when weaving 
[Xlint:cantFindType]
```

but the scala code completion now works ok

Comment: Please post this on [scala-ide-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/scala-ide-user)

Answer (score 2):

Would you mind open a bug report on Code Recommenders including a stacktrace in order to fix this?

Comment: Marcel: I found this bug report here: [code assist not working in nightly build + eclipse 4.2 juno](http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001132)

Comment: thanks. the stacktrace there helps. Fix on Recommenders side is in progress. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383395#c4

Comment: Just to let you know: I got the same pb, Eclipse Juno+nightly Scala IDE for Juno builds.

Comment: Getting the same error for Juno + ScalaIDE 2.0.2.  The moment I type "args.", I get this popup.

Comment: Is this a problem in the Scala plugin ? or a bug in Eclipse JDT ? I am having the same problem

Comment: Installed latest Juno few days ago (Juno Service Release 1) with Scala IDE for Eclipse 2.1.0, still the same problem. Although it seems after these errors show, automatic content suggestion works well for the scala classes contained in my project, so it looks like only a nuisance getting these two messages on every type of a dot. Are you sure it was solved?